# We will do, then hear

Tags: har-sinai

The gemara in shabbath [88a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.88a.8) relates:

> אָמַר רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר: בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁהִקְדִּימוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל ״נַעֲשֶׂה״ לְ״נִשְׁמָע״ יָצְתָה בַּת קוֹל וְאָמְרָה לָהֶן: מִי גִּלָּה לְבָנַי רָז זֶה שֶׁמַּלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁרֵת מִשְׁתַּמְּשִׁין בּוֹ? דִּכְתִיב: ״בָּרְכוּ ה׳ מַלְאָכָיו גִּבֹּרֵי כֹחַ עֹשֵׂי דְבָרוֹ לִשְׁמֹעַ בְּקוֹל דְּבָרוֹ״ — בְּרֵישָׁא ״עֹשֵׂי״, וַהֲדַר ״לִשְׁמֹעַ״.
> Rabbi Elazar said: When the Jewish people accorded precedence to the declaration “We will do” over “We will hear,” a Divine Voice emerged and said to them: Who revealed to my children this secret that the ministering angels use? As it is written: “Bless the Lord, you angels of His, you mighty in strength, that fulfill His word, hearkening unto the voice of His word” (Psalms 103:20). At first, the angels fulfill His word, and then afterward they hearken.

Well, who was it that revealed this secret to the Israelites?

Answer (score 3):

I understand this Gemara as rhetorical. It is not actually saying someone revealed the secret to them, but is praising them for arriving at the conclusion on their own.

A similar expression we may use that is akin to this, is if someone got us a gift that we wanted, we may exclaim "How did you know I wanted that?!" We do not actually expect to hear a coherent answer to this, but it is a way of expressing praise.

Comment: I like the response. Is there anyone who corroborates your answer?